# Combinatorics problem: "partial" permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have 24 items. 16 of them are distinct, 8 are duplicates (one or more) of some of the 16 distinct types. The order of the 24 items does matter to me. I'm trying to compute the number of permutations of these 24 items, but I don't want to include permutations where an item just "swaps places" with its duplicate. I.e. given items like A, B, B1, C, D, E, E1 (where B1 is a duplicate of B, and E1 is a duplicate of E) I don't want to count variations such as these as separate cases:

```
A, B, B1, C, D...
A, B1, B, C, D...

A, B, B1, C, D, E, E1...
A, B, B1, C, D, E1, E...
```

If I had 24 distinct items, the answer would be 24!, if I had 16 distinct items the answer would be 16!. I think what I'm looking for is equal to 24! - [excluded cases], but I'm not sure how to compute the "excluded cases" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the exact distribution of the $8$ duplicates. For example, suppose that $1$ of them is a duplicate of $A$, $2$ of them are duplicates of $B$, and $5$ of them are duplicates of $C$. Then we would have:
$$
\dfrac{24!}{(1+1)!(1+2)!(1+5)!}
$$
In general, suppose that there are $n$ types of duplicates and that for each $k \in \{1,2,...,n\}$, $x_k$ represents the number of duplicates of type $k$ so that $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=8$. Then we obtain:
$$
\dfrac{24!}{(1+x_1)!(1+x_2)!\cdots(1+x_n)!}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the rapid reply. The particular distribution I have is 4 duplicates of A, 2 of B, 2 of C, so I guess the denominator would be (1+2)!*(1+2)!*(1+4)!.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the formula is $ \frac{n!}{p!q!} $.
For instance, the seven-letter words made from the letters in the word "arrange" is $ \frac{7!}{2!2!} $ because there are seven letters and "a" and "r" are repeated twice. None of the others are repeated, so they don't count in the formula.